# prestashop 1.6 get all products

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I want to get all products of my Prestashop 1.6.

Can someone learn me to get all products?
Something like

```
    $products = Controller::getAllProducts();
```

or

```
    $products = Controller::getProducts();
```

And if this is not possible, how get products by category using a HTML select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your module or custom controller type:

```
$products = Product::getProducts($this->context->language->id, 1, 5000, 'name', 'ASC');
```

The prototype of getProducts() method is:

```
  /**
    * Get all available products
    *
    * @param int $id_lang Language id
    * @param int $start Start number
    * @param int $limit Number of products to return
    * @param string $order_by Field for ordering
    * @param string $order_way Way for ordering (ASC or DESC)
    * @return array Products details
    */
    public static function getProducts($id_lang, $start, $limit, $order_by, $order_way, $id_category = false, $only_active = false, Context $context = null)
```

Comment: Can we filter only virtual products from it ?

Comment: @newphpdev As far as I remember on the 1.6 there should be a method that retrieves only the virtual products (that isn't getProducts), check in the Class